# Reorganizing a formula containing Modulo

Tags: algorithm, math, puzzle, modulo

I have a formula that looks like
a = (b + 1 + c)%d
I want to express c in terms of rest, i.e. have "C" on the LHS.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Given `a`, `b`, and `d`, there will be infinitely many values of `c` that solve the equation; which one(s) do you want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
a = (b + 1 + c)%d
a + n*d = b + 1 + c
a -1 - b + n*d = c
```

For any integer `n`.